# How to fix android manifest.xml naming conflict?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, android-manifest

For some reason, even though my app name appeared correctly next to the app icon, when I looked for the app under settings->app, the name appeared to be "libcocos2dx" instead of the correct name.

So I added the following line in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```

But it caused the error:

```
app/AndroidManifest.xml:12:6 Error:
    Attribute application@label value=(@string/app_name) from AndroidManifest.xml:12:6
    is also present at proj.android-studio:libcocos2dx:unspecified:13:9 value=(libcocos2dx)
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:11:5 to override
```

How can I fix the above error ? I have no idea where libcocos2dx is specified as the name. I am using cocos2d-x v3.7, which uses libcocos2dx.

EDIT: I can see the suggestion to use "tools:replace" , but I feel like I'm masking the problem instead of fixing it. Is there a better way to fix the root cause ?

EDIT: Does anyone know how to add tools:replace ? This might seem obvious to you, but when I add it, I get the error:

> the prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:replace" associated with an
>   element type "application" is not bound

Comment: add `tools:replace="android:label` in your `Application` Tag in your `Androidmanifest`.

Comment: Yes I saw that, but why is my app being named libcocos2dx ? How do I fix the original error. I feel like I'm masking the error instead of fixing it.

Comment: Its telling you that that attribute has already been used by libcocos and you have to replace it to override it. Just read the error carefully, its all there

Comment: can you check your `@string/` where it is pointing you?

Comment: @ElefantPhace Yes - I see it. But I don't know how to fix it. I'm new to Android, and don't know these things.

Comment: @Shvet I don't know what you mean. It clearly says app_name

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Had to add to the manifest header:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

For example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourpackage"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Then in the  element:

```
'tools:replace="android:label"'
```

Comment: where 'tools:replace="android:label"' we use?

Answer (score 2):

[The answer from Kaizer Sozay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32033581/477550) in this thread helped me a lot while I was looking to set `android:allowBackup` in my NativeScript project.

I ended up with the complete file like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application tools:replace="android:allowBackup" android:allowBackup="true">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Take a look at who asked the question :)

Comment: Actually both my question and the answer you linked to are mine :)

Comment: Yeah @KaizerSozay I realised that after I posted the answer. I wanted to make sure people searching for NativeScript with the same error came across this answer too. :)

Comment: Haha I have no idea what nativescript is. Have a good one beeman! Can’t wait for your movie!! 